# Start Date Calculation in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, calculated-columns

Recently Google analytics became available as an add on for google sheets.
It is fairly intuitive however I need a way to auto calculate the start date of a month starting with todays date eg today is the 11/02/15 so I would like it to return the 01/02/15 utilising the available date functions. 
My purpose is to run a report for this months data only which can be updated as the month continues. In the next month it would need to start again.
I have an absolute fix but this is not scalable, If you have a function based solution please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
=eomonth(today(),-1)+1
```

is a formula that takes the date for today, finds the end of the preceeding month and then adds one day.

Comment: Thank you, how would I then find the end of this month using the same idea